# Declaring an entity with a column refers to the entity itself

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I am using  "@nestjs/typeorm": "^8.0.3" in my NestJS project.

I have an `Student` entity defined:

```
@Entity('students')
export class Student {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ type: 'bigint' })
  id: string;

  ...

  @Column({})
  assistant: Student;
  
}
```

I have an `assistant` column which is also a `Student`.  What is the right way to refer to the same Entity type inside the entity?

(The relationship between `assistant`(which is also a `student`) and `student` is that one assistant can have multiple students, but one student can have only one assistant.)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a Many to One relationship: Many students to one assistant.

```
@ManyToOne(() => Student)
assistant: Student;
```